# prev/next hide and show divs by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to move into divs, I created next and prev tags. I have two divs class that contains some divs. At a time only two divs can be displayed, one from `class:"divs1"` and another part of it from `class:divs2.` Here is html code:

```
<div class="divs1">
    <div class="test1 "> Show div 1 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1 "> Show div 2 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1 "> Show div 3 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1 "> Show div 4 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1 "> Show div 5 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1 "> Show div 6 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1 "> Show div 7 part 1</div>
</div>
<div class="divs2">
    <div class="test2 "> Show div 1 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2 "> Show div 2 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2 "> Show div 3 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2 "> Show div 4 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2 "> Show div 5 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2 "> Show div 6 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2 "> Show div 7 part 2</div>
</div>
<br/> 
<a id="next">next</a>
<a id="prev">prev</a>
```

I tried to do it something like this, but the problem is when I try to check if there are divs visible or not. My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".divs1 .test1").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });
    $(".divs2 .test2").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs test:visible").next().length != 0 && $(".divs2 test2:visible").next().length !=0 ) 
            $(".divs1 test1:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
            $(".divs2 test2:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs test:visible").prev().length != 0 && $(".divs2 test2:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".divs1 test1:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
            $(".divs2 test2:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Jsfiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/egzontina/hsJbu/781/)
Any help :(

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Thank you for posting your code. If it is not too much to ask, could you make a jsfiddle or code snippet (the question editor allows for code snippets)?

Comment: @www139 i created my jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you. Again, welcome to stack overflow :)

Comment: My answer is on the way :)

Comment: One issue is that you forgot the href attribute for the `<a>` tags. This is required as far as I know. Just put `href="#"` if you don't want it to go anywhere. That isn't the only problem though.

Comment: Based on the way you've formatted your code it looks like you're missing brackets around your `if` statements.

Comment: @Wex I added { } but still it's not working...

Comment: I finished my answer. If you don't like it, I can make it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You may want to add functions to save from having to execute everything twice.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var divs1Active = document.getElementById('divs1Active');
  var divs2Active = document.getElementById('divs2Active');
  $('#next').click(function(){
    //see if there is another element after the divs1Active element before proceeding
    if(divs1Active.nextElementSibling){
      $(divs1Active).hide();
      $(divs2Active).hide();
      $(divs1Active).next().show();
      $(divs2Active).next().show();
      divs1Active.id = '';
      divs2Active.id = '';
      divs1Active.nextElementSibling.id = 'divs1Active';
      divs2Active.nextElementSibling.id = 'divs2Active';
      divs1Active = document.getElementById('divs1Active');
      divs2Active = document.getElementById('divs2Active');
    }
  });
  
  $('#prev').click(function(){
    //if there is a previous sibling to the divs1Active element
    if(divs1Active.previousElementSibling){
      $(divs1Active).hide();
      $(divs2Active).hide();
      $(divs1Active).prev().show();
      $(divs2Active).prev().show();
      divs1Active.id = '';
      divs2Active.id = '';
      divs1Active.previousElementSibling.id = 'divs1Active';
      divs2Active.previousElementSibling.id = 'divs2Active';
      divs1Active = document.getElementById('divs1Active');
      divs2Active = document.getElementById('divs2Active');
    }
  });
};
```

```css
.test1{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #B5B5B5;
    display:none;
}
.test2{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #B5E2B5;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs1" id="divs1">
    <div class="test1 " style="display:block;" id="divs1Active"> Show div 1 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1 "> Show div 2 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1 "> Show div 3 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1 "> Show div 4 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1 "> Show div 5 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1 "> Show div 6 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1 "> Show div 7 part 1</div>
</div>
<div class="divs2" id="divs2">
    <div class="test2 " style="display:block;" id="divs2Active"> Show div 1 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2 "> Show div 2 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2 "> Show div 3 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2 "> Show div 4 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2 "> Show div 5 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2 "> Show div 6 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2 "> Show div 7 part 2</div>
</div>
<br/> 
<a href="#" id="next">next</a>
<a href="#" id="prev">prev</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible culprits for your unsatisfactory results. The previous comment was correct about adding `href="#"` to your `a` anchor tags.

**The HTML need not be changed otherwise** and can safely remain as follows:

```
<div class="divs1">
    <div class="test1"> Show div 1 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1"> Show div 2 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1"> Show div 3 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1"> Show div 4 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1"> Show div 5 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1"> Show div 6 part 1</div>
    <div class="test1"> Show div 7 part 1</div>
</div>
<div class="divs2">
    <div class="test2"> Show div 1 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2"> Show div 2 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2"> Show div 3 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2"> Show div 4 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2"> Show div 5 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2"> Show div 6 part 2</div>
    <div class="test2"> Show div 7 part 2</div>
</div>
<br/> 
<a id="next" href="#">Next</a>
<a id="prev" href="#">Prev</a>
```

**The CSS also need not be changed.**

**The Javascript could use some debugging and optimizing.** For instance, to avoid difficult debugging, I'd suggest always using the explicit blocked `if` statement.
For example:

```
if (condition)
    alert("A");
    alert("B");
```

results in only `"A"` being alerted while the indentation suggests both `"A"` and `"B"` will be alerted. Therefore, adding `{` and `}` around the appropriate code will provide the results you seek and make debugging much easier. e. g.:

```
if (condition) {
    alert("A");
    alert("B");
}
```

Lastly, I'd suggest storing the unchanging results of your `$()` invocations in local variables to spare some invocations and make intent a little clearer. All told, the Javascript could look like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var part1divs = $(".divs1 .test1"),
        part2divs = $(".divs2 .test2"),

        next = $("#next"),
        prev = $("#prev"),

        visFilter = ":visible";

    function hideAllExceptFirst(index) {
        if (index > 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    }

    part1divs.each(hideAllExceptFirst);
    part2divs.each(hideAllExceptFirst);

    next.click(function() {
        var div1vis = part1divs.filter(visFilter),
            div2vis = part2divs.filter(visFilter);

        if (div1vis.next().length > 0) {
            div1vis.next().show().prev().hide();
        }
        if (div2vis.next().length > 0) {
            div2vis.next().show().prev().hide();
        }

        return false;
    });

    prev.click(function() {
        var div1vis = part1divs.filter(visFilter),
            div2vis = part2divs.filter(visFilter);

        if (div1vis.prev().length > 0) {
            div1vis.prev().show().next().hide();
        }
        if (div2vis.prev().length > 0) {
            div2vis.prev().show().next().hide();
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/hsJbu/785/).